# Berryboot issue with opengl es

Tags: berryboot

I have dual booted my raspberry pi with Android auto and raspbian Jesse. I have installed kivy on raspbian for running an application. For this I enabled the opengl es 2.0 driver from raspi-config but now the pi directly boots into raspbian and doesn't load up the berryboot UI first.If I disable it then it shows the berryboot first and allows me to choose my os and works as expected. Any solutions how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with BerryBoot - it is currently not compatible with the OpenGL driver on the Pi.

https://github.com/maxnet/berryboot/issues/430

Comment: Do you know an alternative to opengl which would help and not cause this kind of problem?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is any alternative. My preference is to swap sd cards.

Comment: Have you looked at PINN? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=142574 I've not tried it myself. Please mark the answer if you feel its correct.

Comment: I'm not sure n I also haven't tried. I had read about PINN but I preferred berryboot because I want to install Android auto on my pi so that I can switch between Android auto or raspbian at boot up time. And PINN supports greatly only with few most used os not with Android auto. There is way to convert Android auto to support with PINN but it's too complex for me. Also sticking to the main topic the opengl should cause the same error on PINN because in the cofig.txt there is line 'displayoverlay' or something which needs to be removed.